# Remove annoying line

Tags: html, css

I've deleted the scrollbar but I still see A tiny line

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #B26FFF 0%, rgba(225, 199, 255, 0.79) 100%);
    overflow: clip;
}

.Appname {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: larger;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    align-self: center;
}

.top {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.link-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
    border: none;
}

.link-group a {
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
}

.link-group li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.setting {
    background:local;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/page-styles/index.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/RemistLogo.png.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
    <header class="Appname">Remist</header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="link-group">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="make.html">Make</a></li>
            <li><a href="community.html">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <button class="setting" ><span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span></button> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

1. Tried Chatgpt didnt work
2. Tried Blackbox ai didnt work

3.Tried googling it didnt work

Comment: add the gradient to only the html element and not the body

Answer (score -1):

Try remove `margin` and `padding`.

```css
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, #B26FFF 0%, rgba(225, 199, 255, 0.79) 100%);
        overflow: clip;
    }

    .Appname {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bolder;
        font-size: larger;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        align-self: center;
    }

    .top {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .navbar {
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .link-group {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 20px;
        border: none;
    }

    .link-group a {
        font-size: large;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: white;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .link-group li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .setting {
        background:local;
        border: none;
        float: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/page-styles/index.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@24,400,0,0" />
    <title>HomePage</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/RemistLogo.png.png" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
    <header class="Appname">Remist</header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="link-group">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="make.html">Make</a></li>
            <li><a href="community.html">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <button class="setting" ><span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span></button> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```